# gitlab ci runs a pipeline per stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm working on a project and now I'm adding basic .gitlab-ci.yml file to it. my problem is why gitlab runs a pipeline per stage? what am i doing wrong?

my project structure tree:
[image]

my base .gitlab-ci.yml :

```
stages:
  - analysis
  - test

include:
  - local: 'telegram_bot/.gitlab-ci.yml'
  - local: 'manager/.gitlab-ci.yml'
  - local: 'dummy/.gitlab-ci.yml'

pylint:
  stage: analysis
  image: python:3.8
  before_script:
    - pip install pylint pylint-exit anybadge
  script:
    - mkdir ./pylint
    - find . -type f -name "*.py" -not -path "*/venv/*" | xargs pylint --rcfile=pylint-rc.ini | tee ./pylint/pylint.log || pylint-exit $?
    - PYLINT_SCORE=$(sed -n 's/^Your code has been rated at \([-0-9.]*\)\/.*/\1/p' ./pylint/pylint.log)
    - anybadge --label=Pylint --file=pylint/pylint.svg --value=$PYLINT_SCORE 2=red 4=orange 8=yellow 10=green
    - echo "Pylint score is $PYLINT_SCORE"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./pylint/
    expire_in: 1 day
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - schedules
```

telegram_bot/.gitlab-ci.yml :

```
telbot:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "telbot sample job sucsess."
```

manager/.gitlab-ci.yml :

```
maneger:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "manager sample job sucsess."
```

dummy/.gitlab-ci.yml :

```
dummy:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "dummy sample job sucsess."
```

and my pipelines look like this :
[image: two pipelines]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because your `analysis` stage runs only on `merge_requests` and `schedules` and the other steps you didn't specified when it will run, and, in this case, the jobs will run on every `branches`

When you open the MR, gitlab will run the analysis for the MR (note the `detached` label) and the other three in a separated pipeline.

To fix it, put this in all of the manifests.

```
 only:
    - merge_requests
```

From the docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic

```
If a job does not have an only rule, only: ['branches', 'tags'] is set by default.
```